# WebStorm support for nesting CSS

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am using PostCSS and one of the important elements in PostCSS is CSS nesting. WebStorm doesn't like the syntax and highlights errors.

Is there any solution for this issue?

[image]

Comment: Just as @DanGamble said -- that's the only way for now. In meantime -- consider voting for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16601

Comment: Yep, please vote! Hopefully something gets sorted regarding it soon even if it is just having support for new CSS specification stuff like they did with CSS Variables :)

Answer (score 30):

As of WebStorm 2016.3 this issue has been solved. As detailed in the [WebStorm Blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/08/webstorm-2016-3-early-access-preview/#postcss), users of PostCSS can now install an official PostCSS plugin by navigating to `Preferences > Plugins >` and searching for "PostCSS support". After the plugin is installed and WebStorm has been restarted, you must identify any existing css files using PostCSS as PostCSS by going to `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Stylesheets > Dialects` and clicking on the file's CSS dialect and changing it to "PostCSS".

Comment: Worked for me. I was stuffing around with Stylelint there for awhile, but that didn't work all that well. The plugin mentioned here worked like a charm.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**
Evan's answer below is better now as Webstorm have released an official plugin for PostCSS [WebStorm support for nesting CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867693/webstorm-support-for-nesting-css/41646751#41646751)

Unfortunately, currently the only way to get it to play nice with PostCSS is to do:

[image: css]

Register `*.css` or `*.pcss` if you use that extension to treat them as Sass files inside Webstorm. You'll also need to turn off a few syntax checks Webstorm provides after you change the file type depending on what PostCSS plugins you use.